node spawn process not getting executed when run as systemd service
I am running a node application that is using msmtp to send E-Mails. While simply running the application as a user (e.g. in a screen) it correctly uses my .msmtprc and is able to make our mailserver deliver the mails.
I now installed the application as a systemd service so it gets restarted should it crash for any reason.
The config is:
[UNIT]
Description=MyApp

[SERVICE]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/home/me/app
ExecStart=/usr/bin/npm run start
User=me
Group=me
Restart=always
RestartSec=3

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Everything works fine but the sending of mails. I perform this by spawning a msmtp process and just write the contents of the mail to its stdin:
try {
  const process = child_process.spawn(
    "msmtp",
    ["-t"]
  );
  process.stdin.write("From: " + returnMail + "\n");
  process.stdin.write("MIME-Version: 1.0\n");
  process.stdin.write("Content-Type: text/html\n");
  process.stdin.write("To: " + recepient + "\n");
  process.stdin.write(
    "Subject: Some Subject\n\n"
  );
  process.stdin.write(`<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head><title>Some Subject</title>
<body>
<h1>Something happened</h1>
<h2>Oh No!</h2>
<div>${content}</div>
</body>
</html>`
  );
  process.stdin.end();
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
  return;
}

I do not get any error output (when watching stdout and stderr of the spawned process) or catch an error that would imply that the process was not executed.

It seems that the systemd service can not follow symlinks. I set sendmail as a symlink to msmtp and used sendmail as an alias for msmtp by putting it in my /usr/bin. Using msmtp as the executable like in the above example code works. Using sendmail just doesn't.
